# Unit tests, can you test a single method?

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing

I might be asking something completely obvious. I do not have much experience in writing unit tests, and the following question came up which got me thinking.

Say, you have a class and this class has methods you want to test. But can you test a single method at once? I think not. In order to test the method, you need to invoke one or more other methods. For example:

```
class MyClass { 
    int x;
    void foo() { x = 4; }
    boolean bar() { x = 3; }
    boolean check() { return x == 4; }
}
```

In order to test foo and bar, I need to use check() and on the other hand, in order to test check I need to use either foo() or bar().

Say, I have to following test case:

```
class MyClassTest {
    @Test
    void testFoo() {
        MyClass obj = new MyClass();
        obj.foo();
        assert obj.check();
    }
}
```

Now let's assume, my colleague changes the check() method:

```
boolean check() { return x == 5; }
```

Of course, the testFoo() will fail, and one might think that there is a problem with the foo method.

So this looks like a chicken-egg situation. How do people usually resolve this?

Comment: What is the unit of work? That's generally the scope at which it's applicable to test... sometimes it's as neat as a single method, but frequently you need to create a "fixture" or "suite" to define your "unit of work".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't write tests for individual methods - you write tests for individual requirements. In this case your class seems to have two requirements:

1. "`check` must return `true` when `foo` was called last"
2. "`check` must return `false` when `bar` was called last"

So you would write two unit-tests, one for each requirement to verify that the class fulfills it correctly (you might want to formulate a third requirement: what `check` is supposed to do when neither was called). When your colleague made the change above, he broke neither the `foo` method, not the `check` method. What he broke was the first requirement. Now he has to change the class somehow so that it fulfills it again. How he accomplishes this (change `foo`, change `check`or both) doesn't matter.

Comment: You really answered my question with showing that I am not supposed to test methods, but test behaviours.

Answer (score 5):

It probably doesn't make much sense to test methods independently here because the state of the class can change according to the sequence of methods called. In this case I'd make sure the behavior - or state transitions - work as expected. Please refer to the following three tests which properly specify the behavior of the class:

```
class WhenFooWasCalled {
    @Test
    public void ThenCheckShouldReturnTrue {
        MyClass sut = new MyClass();
        sut.foo();
        assertTrue(sut.check());
    }
}

class WhenBarWasCalled {
    @Test
    public void ThenCheckShouldReturnFalse {
        MyClass sut = new MyClass();
        sut.bar();
        assertFalse(sut.check());
    }
}

class WhenNothingWasCalled {
    @Test
    public void ThenCheckShouldReturnFalse {
        MyClass sut = new MyClass();
        assertFalse(sut.check());
    }
}
```

*Updated: I added a third test case: How does the check() behave if neither foo() nor bar() were called.*

Comment: is it a good idea to have these tests in two different classes?

Comment: @siledh This is completely up to you and a mere matter of style. I prefer the BDD type approach wich helps me to read class name + method name like a sentence, e.g. *WhenFooWasCalled.ThenCheckShouldReturnTrue()*.

Comment: So my assumption was wrong that each method should have a test method, in which you test only that method?

Comment: @DavidFrank Not wrong but it wouldn't help specify the behavior of the class. You expect the class to behave in a specific way, depending on what methods have been called prior to calling `check()`. So this is what you should test.

Comment: +1 for testing behaviour. Testing individual methods because 'you have to' indicates theres something not write with the design of your classes and that the design process (even quickly run through in your head) hasn't been thought through. You may have tested each method but do they actually do something useful?

Answer (score 1):

This is common with a class with internal mutable state. I think your question reduces to your unit tests behaving properly after a given sequence of state manipulations.